# Почему не срабатывает ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Здравствуйте. Вот у меня есть элемент

```
            <div id="delete{{ $match->id }}" class="th-icon">
                <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button" uk-icon="trash"></a>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $match->id }}" name="id">
            </div>
```

по клику на него срабатывает этот ajax,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#delete{{ $match->id }}").click(function(){
            var
                id = $('input[name="id"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url:'/delete',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{id: id},
                success: function(data)
                {

                    console.log(data);
                },
                error:function(data)
                {
                    console.log('2');
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Вот контролер

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $match = Match::find($request->id)->delete();

            return response()->json($match);

    }
```

Рут `Route::post('/delete', 'Admin\MatchController@destroy');`

Ajax данные передает, ошибок нету, по нажатию на элемент он должен удалить запись и сразу пропасть(запись), но запись пропадает после перезагрузки страницы. Как сделать, чтоб запись сразу же пропала?

Comment: Если ajax отрабатывает правильно, то заголовок вопроса стоит поменять. А чтобы после выполнения ajax-запроса удалялся нужный элемент на странице, добавьте после `success: function(data){` что-то вроде  `$('#HTML_ID_нужного_вам_элемента').remove();`

Comment: ммммм... вот оно что, спасиб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После успешного получения ответа в `success` в AJAX, надо удалить элемент в DOM. Для этого можете использовать:

```
$('#ID_элемента').remove();
```

или

```
$('.Класс_элемента').remove();
```

Можно удалить по классу элемента и это еще не ограничение.